# HTML tags are not allowed in the bounty fields

Tags: discussion

[image]

I have seen that [HTML tags are not allowed in the bounty field](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14213/does-a-column-of-marching-soldiers-have-to-break-their-rhythm-while-crossing-a-b).

Is there a way to formatting text in such fields?

Comment: Why are you advertising another question in your bounty notice? That is not what bounties are meant for.

Comment: Carlo, please do not abuse bounties to advertise other questions or to ask for up votes. Moderators can (and will) change bounty messages if they are abused.

Comment: OK @Sklivvz, amend, but this failure does not discourage me for asking better questions, though.

Comment: @Carlo_R. *Voting here works a bit differently from the main site. On Meta, voting is often used to express agreement or disagreement, not to point out a lack of quality or helpfulness. Please don't be concerned if you receive downvotes – members of the community may simply disagree with your bug, feature request, support issue, or the nature of the discussion.* http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq#vote-differences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bounty notices allow the user of mini-markdown:

> Bounty notices will support our Markdown mini format, using the same
>   format as we allow for comments.  The following will be allowed:
>
> ```
> _italic_ and **bold** text,
> inline `code in backticks`,
> and [basic links](http://example.com).
> ```
>
> And just like in comments: line breaks [are not
>   rendered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124016/line-breaks-paragraphs-for-bounty-text).

From https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120346/151385